# Bootstrap 3 modal not appear automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalLogin" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3>Login</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email..."/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password..."/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
                                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to show this modal automatically, with this javascript code:

```
<script>
            $('#myModalLogin').modal({
                show: true
            })
</script>
```

But it seems not work, and i don't understand why.

ps: of course I have included javascript files bootstrap 3:

```
<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Any help and/or direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do not see any issues with your code:

with code

```
$('#myModalLogin').modal({
  show: true
})
```

without it it does not.

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/usecide/99xKj/1/

Comment: I try to explain you the context (if it helps to understand): i've a page .html.php, in which i want to reload the modal of Login if the user don't insert correctly email or password.

Comment: Checking email and password is executed by the controller (a page php), which re-include the template (in which there is the modal) if the login is unsuccessful.

Comment: So, i want to display automatically (controlled by a php global variable) the modal when the login is unsuccessful